# Weasyprint Fontconfig error when importing into python

Tags: python-3.x, weasyprint, fontconfig

When I `import weasyprint` I get the following error:

```
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
```

Is there a way to suppress this error, because the program runs fine otherwise. Better yet, how do I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a *Unix-based OS*, I Think You need to set the `$FONTCONFIG_PATH` properly in your *OS*. Usually it is set in `/etc/profile` but, if you are executing the command from a non login shell (e.g., through a python script or library), then you need to set it explicitly by doing the following command in your shell and And probably your problem will be solved:

```bash
➜ export FONTCONFIG_PATH=/etc/fonts
```